# expected input_2 to have shape (512,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I've trained a GRU with Keras. Getting the error when I ran

`nxt = model.predict([features,embedding_matrix[enc_map[cur]]])`

`ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_2 to have shape (512,) but got array with shape (1,)`

But 
features.shape
(512,)`
And

`embedding_matrix[enc_map[cur]].shape
(50,)`

Here's the summary of the model:

`model.summary()`

```
________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 512)          0
________________________________________________________________________________
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 50)           0
________________________________________________________________________________
merge_1 (Merge)                 (None, 562)          0           input_2[0][0]
                                                                 input_1[0][0]
________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)             (None, 1, 562)       0           merge_1[0][0]
________________________________________________________________________________
gru_1 (GRU)                     (None, 128)          265344      reshape_1[0][0]
_______________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 50)           6450        gru_1[0][0]
================================================================================
Total params: 271,794
Trainable params: 271,794
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The inputs must be a **numpy array** with shape `(any, 512)`

Check out the shape of the `X_train` data you used for training, it must follow the same rules.

If this results in a correct shape, you can:

```
input_data = np.array([features,embedding_matrix[enc_map[cur]]])
```

But if there is anything wrong with this data and it doesn't fit the required `(any,512)`, the model will not be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape the `input_data` array to `(512,1)` and also transpose it.

```
input_data = input_data.reshape(512,1).T
```

Comment: How does this answer the original question? Mind going into some detail?

Comment: Please provide reasons behind your suggestion, and how it answers the question.